# When does a conic represents a pair of planes?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given a conic equation
$$H:= ax^2+by^2+cz^2+2fyz+2gzx+2hyx=0,$$

What is (are) the conditions on the coefficients that it represents a pair of planes?

I know that if this is true, then $H$ can be written as 
$$H=(px+qy+rz)(sx+ty+uz)$$
for some constants $p, q, r, s,t, u$. Expanding gives

$$ps x^2 + qt y^2 + ruz^2 + (pt+qs)xy+ (pu+ rs) xz+ (qu+rt) yz = H,$$

which gives us a system of $6$ equations
\begin{align}
ps &=a \\ 
qt &= b \\ 
ru &= c \\
pt+qs &= 2f \\
pu + rs &= 2g \\
qu+ rt &= 2h. 
\end{align}

The algebra gets a little bit too messy for me and I do not know how to move on. In the solution, it is given that 
$$f^2 \geq bc, \ \ g^2 \geq ac, \ \ h^2 \geq ab $$

and the determinant of some minor of 
\begin{pmatrix} 
a & h & g \\ h & b & f \\ g & f & c 
\end{pmatrix}
are zero.

Comment: Any thoughts of your own?

Comment: Actually, I am ambiguous. In a text, it was given that some  determinant is zero and $f^2\geq bc$, $g^2\geq ac$ and $h^2\geq ab$. But I think these conditions $f^2\geq bc$, $g^2\geq ac$ and $h^2\geq ab$. are obvious.

Comment: Here's a small hint: Why don't you start with the equation of a pair of planes and see what that will look like? How do you get a *pair* of planes? Start with an easy case, like the $xy$-plane and the $xz$-plane.

Comment: I know the solution part, but are the conditions $f^2\geq bc$, $g^2\geq ac$ and $h^2\geq ab$ necessary?

Answer (score 3):

We can confirm that

$$f^2 \geq bc, \ \ g^2 \geq ac, \ \ h^2 \geq ab$$

and the determinant of a certain matrix equal to $0$ are necessary conditions.

Here is how. The quadratic form can be written under a matrix form as follows :

$$\tag{1}\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c
\end{bmatrix}}_Q\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If the quadratic form can be expressed as the product of two linear forms (when we will equal it to zero, we will get the equations of the two planes *passing through the origin*):

$$2(px+qy+rz)(sx+ty+uz).$$

The equivalent matrix form of this expression is (many thanks to @Will Jagy) :

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
p\\q\\r\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
s&t&u
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
s\\t\\u\\
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
p&q&r
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{bmatrix}=$$

$$\tag{2}\begin{bmatrix}
x&y&z
\end{bmatrix}\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
2ps&(pt+qs)&(pu+rs)\\(pt+qs)&2qt&(qu+rt)\\(pu+rs)&(qu+rt)&2ru\end{bmatrix}}_Q
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And yes, comparing (1) and (2), we check that necessarily, for example the "diagonal minor":

$$\begin{vmatrix}
b&f\\f&c
\end{vmatrix}=bc-f^2=4qurt-(qu+rt)^2=-(qu-rt)^2 \leq 0$$

the same for the other expressions...

Remark : As we can write :

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
p&s\\q&t\\r&u
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
s&t&u\\p&q&r
\end{bmatrix},
$$

the rank of $Q$ is at most 2.

Thus, $det(Q)=0$.

The rank of $Q$ falls to $1$  iff $\begin{bmatrix}
p\\q\\r
\end{bmatrix}$ and $
\begin{bmatrix}
s\\t\\u
\end{bmatrix}
$ are proportional (the case of a double plane).

Comment: Jean, I got the symmetric matrix form of the product of two linears was $P S^T + S P^T,$ where $P$ and $S$ are yor column vectors of coefficients. In particular, symmetric matrix was rank two when $P,S$ not parallel.

Comment: @Will Jagy Hello ! Maybe you have seen the counterexample I gave to Bernard with the rank-2 matrix obtained by taking $a=h=1$ and $b=2$, all the other coefficients beeing $0$ : You get $(x+y)^2+y^2$ which is equal to $0$ iff $y=-x=0$ which is a degenrate case, but not the kind we are looking for.

Comment: @Will Jagy (ctd...) Your expression is exact $X^T(PS^T+SP^T)X=2(X^TP)(X^TS)$ (due to commutativity of scalars), but still rank 1. This said, this expression is very valuable because you have at once a symmetrical matrix, whereas the expression I get in (3) does not "look" symmetrical (one has to add supplementary conditions, like $rt=qu$, etc.

Comment: @Will Jagy I must leave now, but I will think a little more about your expression $PS^T+SP^T$...

Comment: Jean, Thanks,  I will check here tomorrow

Comment: @Will Jagy One thing is sure, we haven't to consider the (degenerate) case of parallel planes because all planes here must contain the origin.

Comment: @Will Jagy Thanks to you, I have spotted my error and corrected it. You are right : the matrix is rank-2. I have  written a new version, that, I think, is the correct one...

Comment: Looks good to me. I upvoted a few minutes ago. It must be pretty late where you live.

Comment: @Will Jagy Yes, pretty late... Thanks.

Comment: Next day. It would probably have made more sense if I said that I had calculated the Hessian matrix

Comment: @Will Jagy I look forward to see the way you have been driven to this interesting form.

Comment: It was quite visual. Let us see if the system will let me post the four expressions in comment(s).  $$ (Ax + By + C z)(Dx + Ey + Fz) = $$
$$ AD x^2 + BE y^2 + CF z^2 + (BF+CE) yz + (AF+CD) zx + (AE+BD) xy $$ $$
H = 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2AD & AE +BD & AF +CD \\
AE + BD & 2BE & BF + CE \\
AF + CD & BF+CE & 2CF \\
\end{array}
\right) =
$$  $$
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 AD & BD & CD \\
 AE & BE & CE \\
 AF & BF  & CF \\
\end{array}
\right)
+ 
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 AD & AE  & AF \\
 BD & BE & BF \\
 CD & CE& CF \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Very interesting. I scratch my head : this case of "two planes degeneracy" allows to interpret the matrix of our quadratic form as a certain Hessian with the form $PS^T+SP^T$, which, besides,  has eigenvalues $(0, \lambda_1 \geq 0,  \lambda_2 \leq 0)$ (I haven't a real proof, it is only based on extensive simulations). Does this constitutes a characterization of this case ? Hum, hum...

Comment: I get to $PS^T+SP^T$ by analogy to the 2-D case of intersecting lines: We have $\mathbf x^TPS^T\mathbf x=0$ as an equation of the two planes. Symmetrizing for the quadratic form gives some multiple of $PS^T+SP^T$.

Comment: A pair of intersecting planes is a degenerate hyperbolic cylinder, so we expect a spectrum of $+$$-$$0$. Its principal axes are the angle bisectors of $P$ and $S$, with eigenvalues $P^TS\pm\|P\|\|S\|$ along with the null vector $P\times S$. Cauchy-Schwarz gives you the signs of these eigenvalues.

Comment: @amd Thank you ! Everything becomes clear now with this explanation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *quadratic form*, which is associated with the symmetric matrix
$$Q_H=\begin{bmatrix}
a&h&g\\h&b&f\\g&f&c
\end{bmatrix}$$
and the quadric is degenerate if and only if the discriminant of $H$, i.e. $\det Q_H$ is $0$.

Comment: (ctd...) or example taking $a=h=1, b=2$ and all other coefficients set to $0$, you have $(x+y)^2+y^2$. Setting this expression to zero, you get a degenerate case which is a line (with equations $y=-x=0$), but not a pair of planes.

Comment: I am not the downvoter ! I am fully aware that in this kind of situations, there are subtle differences and degeneracies of one kind that aren't degeneracies of another kind...

Comment: I was completly wrong about rank=1 !!! (I have erased it because it would mislead a future reader, but I recognize my error). Thanks to a remark of @Will Jagy I have written a new version. I was right only on one thing: the remark about subtleties of this kind of situations...

Comment: @Jean Marie: I focused  only on the degeneracy criterion, not the type of degeneracy.

Comment: That's right. And there are other degeneracy cases than those that have been considered. Regards.